# Spark: merging RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

How to deal with the RDD structure: after calling "map" function I get a RDD where `myObject` is my own class consisting on a serialization of a xml.

I want to merge every `myObject` of the RDD into one.

I have implemented the `foreach` function and called a specific function inside it but the problem is that there is a lot of `myObject` so it spends many time.

*Edit: piece of code implemeting 'reduce':

```
  JavaRDD<MyObject> objects = null;
  objects = input.map(new Function<String, MyObject>() { public MyObject call(String s) throws MalformedURLException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException{
      machine.initializeReader(delimiter);
      return machine.Request(s);
  }
  });

  MyObject finalResult = objects.reduce(new Function2<MyObject, MyObject, MyObject>() {
  @Override
  public MyObject call(MyObject myObject, MyObject myObject2) {
      return myObject.merge(myObject2);
  }
  });
```

'Merge' function loops through 'MyObject' elements and merge common ones: if I have a tag with specific id and the same in the other "myObject' then I create a result containing the tag and adding 2.

The problem using 'reduce' or 'foreach' is the spent time.

Thanks

Comment: a minimally reproducible example would make it much easier help

Comment: Can you use the reduce function? If your merge function is commutative and associative it should be more efficient.

Comment: Also, please explain what kind of merge operation you want to do on myObject.